# how to set text highlight color in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, text, textarea, highlight

I want to set the background color or highlight color of selected text in text area in Flex as we can set highlight color of text in MS Word.

And after setting this highlight color user can also edit this text without disappearing this highlight color.

Please help me doing this.

Any help or any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the TextRange class to hightlight text it highlights

[Text Highlighter](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/01/using-the-textrange-class-to-hightlight-text/)

Then add the keypress eventListener for the textArea and check with proper condition

and set the text Highlighter during edit.

Comment: I have used TextRange it only apply color to text. But i want to apply background color to this text.